# Time stamp the current date into a google text document?

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, google-docs

Reading all the relevant topics doesn't get me to the solution :

**using an I-Phone**, i need to "timestamp" a google text document. (text, no spreadsheet ! ).

*I do it easily to a spreadsheet*.

**Is this possible in a text document**? For example typing in a short cut, like "ddd" or whatever, automatically replaced by the current date ?

Other ideas ?

*I need this process to keep notes on pianist's work, during real-time music lessons. 
No time to search in custom menus, or typing the full date. Teaching comes first, no distraction, my rule is to preserve and strengthen the link 'pupil-teacher'...*

Comment: How do use this text document? Are you talking about Google Doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay here's a simplification:**

Just to be clear we're opening up a Google Doc file and then going to the script editor.

In the script editor create a new html file named 'sidebar'.  Put the following code in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Add TimeStamp" onClick="google.script.run.addTimeStamp()" style="width:250px;height:150px;text-align:center;margin:10px 0 10px 0;vertical-align:top;" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Then put the following code in the Code.gs file:

```
function onOpen()
{
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
    .addItem('Show Sidebar','showSideBar' )
    .addToUi();
}

function addTimeStamp()
{
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph(ts);
}

function showSideBar()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function doGet()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar');
  return ui.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Save everything in the script editor.  Now close the Google Docs file which will also close the script editor and open it again.  After a short time the menu called My Menu will appear. Open the menu and click on 'Show SideBar' you should see a sidebar appear on the right hand side of the screen.  It should have one button on it. Click it and you should see a timestamp appear on the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cooper. My points : **1)** Possible to run the addTimeStamp function directly from the document? _(not from the script editor)_ **2)** I-phone/ iOS doesn't allow buttons to run scripts... **3)** Your code "<input type="button"... refers to html coding ? **4)** is a sidebar visible on I-phone? **5)** some links to understand "webapp? Sorry for my newbie questions!... and tks again for helping. Eric :-)

Comment: You can add the button to a sidebar or a menu.  You also run it as a webapp with only one button on any computer including an iphone as long as your logged on to Google as yourself.  The HTML coding is for the sidebar, a dialog or [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: @  Cooper, thanks this is pretty new to me, and "foggy"... I tried to run your scripts, I get back an error, running the onOpen for the first time. Do you know what happens? I am a little bit lost.. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: thanks again. Unfortunately, the menu _'my menu'_ doesn't appear. Does this work on your own system ? I am sure to save, and do exactly what you propose. i am sorry to be stuck, and sorry for your time. I don't know what to do... Thanks for all your answers...

Comment: It does work on my system.  I've tested all of the code including using it as a webapp.

Comment: May be it's a local problem server-side. I'll check in the morning( french schedule). Have a nice evening. :-)

Comment: I think the Google Servers are having some serious problems because I tried running it in a new file on the same account and there it fails.  I'll return to it in a few hours.

Comment: Hello. 07:00 am in France. Script works, onOpen creates menu and sidebar, TimeStamp button ok. Webapp get back an error : **Fonction de script introuvable : doGet**. Do you think is due to server again ?

Comment: You probably don't need the webapp.  It's just a button. But inorder to create the webapp you'll need publish as a webapp in the script editor.

Comment: I absolutly need the webapp, so useful on I-Phone.  The menu sidebar doesn't appear on I-Phone right ? I deployed it as a webapp... no succes. doGet error remains... I have other choices under deploy as webapp. is the second or the third good to try ?

Comment: I think I always use the top one and I make it so that only I can use it

Comment: You just have to Deploy as web app and I make it so only I can use it.  But this app just has a button on it which puts a timestamp in the doc that contains it.  So if you also  want to add notes to it you'll probably want to add that feature as well.  I have another app that I use to help me to remember things that creates a list of time stamped notes and that code is available from [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/time-stamped-notes).